# How can I get the output from Image Trace to be Strokes instead of a Fill?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace

I need to trace picture below to vector.

[image]

After tracing it with black and white mode I got result below that I don't like. I would like to have all lines to be in the same constant width.

[image]

What tracing strategy I should use to get needed result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using image trace, I think the default method is to use fill. You can change this in the Image Trace Panel.

Under the Advance options -> Create: make sure Stroke is checked.

[image: Image Trace Options]

The result

[image: the result of image trace]

You can then use Object -> Expand and then move around the anchor points to fix some of the lines.

For best results you can manually trace the image with the pen tool.

Comment: How to trace image with pen tool? Should I create new layer over exiting pixel image and redraw everything? Is it possible somehow ask system to snap lines to pixel image lines?

Comment: @vico You can put this image on layer 1 and make the pen path on layer 2 (I don't think it matters if you do it on 1 layer if you lock the picture). To my knowledge I don't think there is any "snap to pixel image when using the pen tool".